# `warm_start` Parameter And Its Impact On Computational Time

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gradient-descent, hyperparameters

I have a [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) model with a defined set of parameters (`warm_start=True`).

As always, I call `LogisticRegression.fit(X_train, y_train)` and use the model after to predict new outcomes.

Suppose I alter some parameters, say, `C=100` and call `.fit` method again using the **same training data**.

---

Theoretically, for the second time, I think `.fit` should take less computational time as compared to the model with `warm_start=False`. However, empirically is not actually true.

Please, help me understand the concept of `warm_start` parameter.

> P.S.: I have also implemented `SGDClassifier()` for an experimentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you understand the concept of using the previous solution as an initialization for the following fit with `warm_start=True`.

[Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) states that `warm_start` parameter is useless with *liblinear* solver as there is no working implementation for a special linear case. To add, *liblinear* solver is a default choice for `LogisticRegression` which basically means that weights will be completely reinstantiated before each new fit.

To utilize `warm_start` parameter and reduce the computational time you should use one of the following solvers for your `LogisticRegression`:

- **newton-cg** or **lbfgs** with a support of L2-norm penalty. They are also usually better with multiclassification problems;
- **sag** or **saga** which converge faster on larger datasets than *liblinear* solver and use multinomial loss during descent.

---

#### Simple example

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
y = [1, 0, 1]

# warm_start would work fine before each new fit
clf = LogisticRegression(solver='sag', warm_start=True)

clf.fit(X, y)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, @E.Z. Initially, when I studied the documentation, I read it but while experimenting, I missed this point.