# LogisticRegression() training with pre-trained model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, pre-trained-model

I want to train logistic regression (from sklearn.linear_model) in respect that I have similar, already trained model.

```
pre_trained_model = LogisticRegression()

main_model = LogisticRegression()
```

So my question is HOW I can use the pre-trained model to train the main model?
Is it possible to use warm_start or other parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: IIUC `warm_start` is indeed what you're looking for, here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/61596745/9698684

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651096/warm-start-parameter-and-its-impact-on-computational-time